# Android Kitkat Default SMS app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Good noon,

I have developed an application that listen about some special sms from some selected numbers on android pre Kitkat and on Kitkat also it will run smoothly on pre kitkat version but on Kitkat due to default sms app when a sms received from other number than selected numbers then it will not allow to go to inbox is it possible when an sms received and it is not related with app then default app allow to go it to inbox please specifies me an answer ..
thanks in advance.

thanks n regards 
Om Parkash..

Answer (score 0):

If you need an SMS to go to your app and only your app, use port based SMS.  It's basically a socket that uses SMS to send the data, and is not added to the normal messaging app.